# End keyword in print statement is not working in Python UBUNTU

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, runtime-error

The end keyword used with print statement is not working in my PYTHON UBUNTU(neither in sublime nor in pycharm ce nor in terminal.
Not even by importing sys and time

I tried importing sys and time and using time.sleep(),sys.stdout.write(), sys.stdout.flush() too

This Is the Code

```
print("Hi",end=" ")
print("hello")
```

Error Message:

```
file "/home/ansh/Desktop/fun.py", line 3
print("Hello", end = " ")
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/ansh/Desktop/fun.py"]
[dir: /home/ansh/Desktop]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:                /bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

Comment: You're trying to use Python 3 syntax in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Python 2.x instead of 3.x.

The same thing can be achieved in Python 2.x with this:

```py
print "Hi", 
print "hello"
```